# How do you write out-of-line constructor with template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constructor

Lets say I have the following struct. How would I write the out-of-line constructor for this?

```c++
template <typename T>
struct foo
{
    template <typename Bar>
    foo(int n, Bar bar);
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would need two separate template declarations:

```
template <typename T>
template <typename Bar>
foo<T>::foo(int n, Bar bar)
{
    // ...
}
```